# /client/imports vs /imports in Socially demo app vs Meteor official app structure?

Tags: angular2-meteor

First day playing with angular2-meteor and going through the Socially tutorial app I noticed that it puts the `imports` directory in the `client` folder, whereas the official Meteor guidelines suggest a top level directory for `imports`?

Socially demo app guidance: https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/adding-removing-objects-and-angular-event-handling

Meteor Structure guidance: http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure

Just wanted to see if the reason for placing in `client` folder was something to do with Angular2 or just a preference?

Secondly, if so, does that mean that Meteor picks up any directory called `imports` regardless of where it's saved for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is just a matter of preference for the tutorial. Meteor will treat any `/imports` folder the same regardless of location. You can keep it in the `/client` folder or create a root level `/imports` folder. It doesn't really matter.